# How do i set WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE for writeCharacteristic for rxandroidble

Tags: android, rxandroidble

Here is my code.I can't find a way to set it.

```
 device.establishConnection(false).timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).retry(3)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection ->
                        rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(fromString("0004444-0000-1000-8000-00804444fb"), hexToBytes(mData))
                                .timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).retry(3
                ).take(1)
                .subscribe(

                        characteristicValue -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "write success  " + device.getMacAddress());
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "write error " + throwable + " device " + device.getMacAddress());
                        }
                );
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current API of the library there is no easy possibility to use a specific write type for each write operation and you need to set it on the side.

```
device.establishConnection(false)
  .timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // off-topic this seem to be quite short timeout for the action
  .retry(3)
  .flatMap(RxBleConnection::discoverServices, (rxBleConnection, rxBleDeviceServices) ->
    rxBleDeviceServices.getCharacteristic(fromString("0004444-0000-1000-8000-00804444fb"))
      .flatMap(characteristic -> {
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE); // here you set the write type
        return rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, hexToBytes(mData)) // and then execute the write
          .timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .retry(3);
      })
  )
  .flatMap(observable -> observable)
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(
    characteristicValue -> {
      Log.e(TAG, "write success  " + device.getMacAddress());
    },
    throwable -> {
      Log.e(TAG, "write error " + throwable + " device " + device.getMacAddress());
    }
  );
```

There is an ongoing [pull request](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/pull/239) to add a new API that would expose the `.setWriteType()` method.

Note: not all characteristics support `WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE`. You can check wether one does by checking `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getProperties()`

Comment: Is it a requirement that the writeType has to be updated before every write or should it be persisted as long as the connection remains active?

Comment: It is supposed to be persisted, i.e. the library does not change the writeType on its own

Comment: Thanks Dariusz! I was able to confirm through testing that this is the case however I was also surprised to see that for some ble devices, the default write type was already set to `WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE` if the device supported it. Thanks for your response!